# Perl Regular expression look ahead

Tags: regex, perl

What is the use of
    ?= 
in perl regex
please tell the exact meaning and give some regex example.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=...)
```

is a positive lookahead, a type of zero-width assertion. What it's saying is that the  match must be followed by whatever is within the parentheses but that part isn't captured.

Example:

```
.*(?=bar)
```

This pattern matches all the characters upto the string `bar`. When `bar` is detected then it stops matching. If a line contains more than one `bar` means it matches upto the last `bar` because `.*` does a greedy match.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/16)